# Problem with test-path on computer from another domain

Tags: powershell

Im trying to test a remote folder in a computer from another domain with -credential

This command works fine:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "server" -credential domain\user -ScriptBlock {Test-Path -Path "\\server\s$\temp"}
```

But if i use it in a script fails:

```
$servers = Get-Content "servers.txt"
$Path = "\\D$\Temp"
$cred = "domain\user"

ForEach ($server in $servers) {

    if (invoke-command -computername $server -credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Test-Path -Path "\\$server\$Path"})
}
```

PD: All this option works in a server of my domain without specify another credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the syntax issue with missing the script block after your if statement, this should work as long as you specify the variables as remote ones. Use `$using` or pass it as an argument with `-ArgumentList`.

```
$servers = Get-Content "servers.txt"
$Path = "\\c$\Temp"
$cred = "domain\user"

ForEach ($server in $servers) {
    if (
        invoke-command -computername $server -ScriptBlock {
            Test-Path -Path "\\$using:server\$using:Path"
        }
    ) { <#do code here#> }
}
```

If you run the shell with the proper credentials to begin with, all youd have to do is use `Test-Path` directly but I understand that you'd like to try using the `-Credential` parameter.

Comment: Using these parameters still doesn't work \\$using:server\$using:Path